# Anchoring first bone in an armature

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

I am getting close to understanding how bones work. Subsequent bones that I add to an armature (and to which I parent objects) will rotate, etc. around where the base of that bone is stuck to the head of the previous bone. But the *first* bone will pivot around the 3D cursor, wherever that is. So if I (inadvertently) move the 3D cursor, suddenly the whole armature will transform around that new point instead.

How do I fix the pivot point of that first bone to a particular point on its parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *first* bone is pivoting around it's *Transform* [pivot point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html).  You get to set what that pivot point is by using a menu in the 3D Viewport's header:

[image: Transform pivot point menu with 3D cursor selected]

How a bone pivots when it is selected depends on whether you are in Object, Edit, or Pose mode.  It also depends on the transform mode.

If you are in *Pose* mode, as it sounds like you are, you may currently have yours set to "3D Cursor".  If you change it to "Individual Origins" it will pivot around its own head, rather than around the 3D cursor.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.